# What Computer Science projects for undergrads are mostly in demand by European and American firms?

Tags: research

Computer Science has a broad spectrum of disciplines ranging from AI, Big Data, Cryptography to Human Computer Interaction and Bioinformatics. I would like to know what projects are ideal for undergrad students of CS among these disciplines that can attract funding from European and American firms.

Comment: These interesting question about career prospects is unfortunately off-topic here.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Comment: Contact firms you are interested in.

Comment: @Raphael Got it. Do you recommend me rephrasing my question? Thank you

Comment: @Maxood It's not a matter of rephrasing. You are asking for a recommendation for your career, which can not have an objective answer. Also, it is not a scientific question, since the answer can change depending on the market's whims. Today, (say) BigData might be in great demand, in 5 years other fields might be.